# Incompatible types when initializing type error

Tags: c, pointers, structure, incompatibletypeerror

I'm facing problems with pointers and structures in C. Let's say:

```
typedef struct mdata{
   int a;
   int b;
    ...
} pred_data_attr;

typedef struct mConfig{
   pred_data_attr mdata;
   ...
} mConfig;

struct control{
   struct mConfig mcfg;
   ...
};

INT32 rdfapp(struct control *rdf){
    pred_data_attr* mdata = rdf->mcfg.mdata;
    ...
}
```

I got this error:

> incompatible types when initializing type 'struct pred_data_attr *' using type 'pred_data_attr'

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please post the code that does the initialization. But judging by your error message you are trying to initialize a pointer type with a struct - which is just plain wrong. A pointer type will take something returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `mmap`, `&` operator or similar. Not a struct.

Comment: Your naming convention is weird (m is prefixed to the names of member variables usually, not type names). What is the definition of `mConfig`? Does it have an `mdata` member which happens to be of type `pred_data_attr*`?

Comment: provide `mConfig` struct details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
INT32 rdfapp(struct control *rdf)
{
  pred_data_attr * mdata = &rdf->mcfg.mdata;
```

---

The namings in your code are another good example how inappropriate naming can lead to irritations and errors.

It is not a good idea to name different things the same:

```
pred_data_attr * mdata /* here mdata is a pointer */

pred_data_attr mdata; /* here mdata is the instance of a structure */
```

There are plenty of possiblilites how naming can be setup, from which I do not want to recommend any here as it's primarily about:

**Give different names to different things.**